# does my meteor app needs both MONGO_OPLOG_URL and MONGO_URL

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm deploying my Meteor app on Modulus.io and for my database using compose.io with oplog, I'm setting up environment url's I wondering if I need both MONGO_OPLOG_URL and MONGO_URL or just the MONGO_OPLOG_URL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MONGO_URL` is the URL your app uses to communicate with your mongo instance. It is required for all production applications. Oplog transactions are **not** communicated through this URL.

`MONGO_OPLOG_URL` is the URL your app uses to [listen for changes](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver) to the binary oplog for your database. It is not required, but highly recommended.

Summary: add both.

For more information see [this article](https://blog.compose.io/meteor-and-compose-a-beginners-guide-to-using-them-together/).